# How to download Microsoft.Bcl.Async package

Tags: c#, async-await

At my work place, we are not allowed to install packages from Nuget, so I am just wondering is there any place to download installer instead, so an internal packaging team can distribute it across the firm.

And is the package production ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is only distributed via NuGet.  You would need to use the package manager to get the assemblies, though you could then just copy the assemblies manually into your system.

> And is the package production ready?

Yes, it is now production ready. The BCL Team just announced that this [package is now considered Stable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx). From their post:

> Being stable means the owner of that package states that API and functionality are unlikely to change and therefore suitable for use in production.

Comment: What assemblies we need to copy to get it working, and I remeber with VS 2010 it applied changes to compiler and copying dlls was not an option, that you had to run the installer.

Comment: @SujithJagini I believe it's a single assembly, now - don't remember exactly, since I"m just using 4.5.  That being said, if you're using VS 2012, you don't need compiler changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could just download the package from another PC (out of work) and then copy the assemblies. Of course you don't get the extra benefits from NuGet, but it's still a viable option.

**EDIT** Just saw that a few days ago the package was declared stable as Reed correctly indicated.